# Ускорьте программу

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

```
count = int(input())
for i in range(1, count + 1):
    a = j = i
    while a < count:
        j += 1
        a += j
    if a == count:
        print(i)
        break
```

Ищется наименьшее **i**, для введённого числа равному **count**.
**i** - это число, при котором последовательность ***i** + (**i** + 1) + (**i** + 2) + ... (i + n) = **count***
При числе 1000001324409 (ответ: 57), тестировочная прога выдаёт:

> *Превышен лимит времени*

По факту прошу придумать новое более быстрое решение.
Спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти минимальный первый член арифметической прогрессии?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340113/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Ну теперь оне все в яндекс или в хаха или в амазон какой поступят ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По формуле суммы арифметической прогрессии

```
sum { j in i to n } of j = (i + i+n) / 2 * (n+1) = i + n*(n+1) / 2
```

Отсюда уравнение:

```
i + n*(n+1) / 2 = count
n**2 + n - 2*(count-i) = 0
D = 1 + 8*(count-i)
```

Если дискриминант является полным квадратом, то последовательность, начинающаяся с `i` существует.

Так что просто перебираем `i` по возрастанию и проверяем, является ли полным квадратом `1 + 8*(count-i)`. Получится линейная асимптотика вместо квадратичной в вопросе.

Comment: cпасибо! Но не могли бы вы объяснить, откуда в формуле (i + i+n) / 2 * (n+1) взялась единица.
И ещё это - Если дискриминант является полным квадратом, то последовательность, начинающаяся с i существует.

Comment: @Petr__, количество чиcел: i=10, n=4: `10,11,12,13,14` => `14-10+1=5=n+1`.

Comment: а ок...........

Answer (score 0):

```
    S1 = int(input())
    S2 = 1
    An1 = 2
    An2 = 1
    while S2 < S1:
        S2 += An1
        An1 += 1
    while S2 != S1:
        S2 -= An2
        if S2 < S1:
            S2 += An1
            An1 += 1
        An2 += 1
    print(An2)
```

Выше вы видите код, как мне кажется, более простого решения для Python.
А ниже разбор алгоритма:

1. Задаём сумму первых членов прогрессии;
2. Находим минимальную сумму арифметической прогрессии, начинающуюся на 1 и большую заданной суммы арифметической прогрессии;
3. По очереди вычитаем из неё все члены, начиная с единицы, и, когда она меньше заданной суммы, прибавляем следующие члены, пока сумма нашей прогрессии не будет равна заданной;
4. Выводим ответ!